# Antivirus keeps blocking connection from a file I don't recognize

Tags: windows, antivirus

This is a follow up to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/668790/how-do-you-find-the-file-that-avast-anti-virus-is-blocking-connections-from-no). I've finally tracked down the file Avast keeps detecting and it's `C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Local\Updater.exe` , I've no clue what this file is for , but am wondering if i should delete it or how I can get Avast to stop detecting it?

Not sure why people are jumping to conclusions and think I'm going to disable my anti-virus. If it's a false positive then I would add it to a list of exceptions. Read the question better and ask if you don't understand instead of down vote.

[image: screenshot]
 When I click more details it doesn't give any more information.

Comment: I don't know what it is + How can I keep my antivirus from detecting it = ¡pwned!

Comment: What is Avast saying when it alerts you?  Generally speaking, AV software doesn't just say "Something wrong here.", you tend to get something more specific.

Comment: @Owen I updated question with screen shot

Comment: as others have said, the AV is doing it's job here.  If you haven't already, run a full scan, and monitor your system closely for odd behaviour, and screen network activity if you are able to.

At this point, I'd say this becomes a question more suited for SuperUser, rather than Security StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, Your Anti-virus is doing it's job and if you do not want it to detect things that can harm your computer, then you should not have installed it in the first place. Do not turn off your AV protection just for the sake of not getting the alerts. It is definitely for your long term good.

However, try to recognize to which software that the Updater.exe belongs and remove it if it is harmful or unknown.

**Main problem with the updaters** : They can download files in your computer and install automatically without your permission if you have left the **Update automatically** option during the installation of the software. If a Trojan program is installed in your system, then it is no longer called "**your system**" in the security circle.

By reading through the [link](http://www.avast.com/en-us/lp-pr-virus-alert?p_ext=&utm_campaign=Virus_alert&utm_source=prg_ise_90_0&utm_medium=prg_systray&utm_content=./paid/en-us/virus-alert-default&p_vir=URL:Mal&p_prc=C:%5CUsers%5CJosh%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CSwvUpdater%5CUpdater.exe&p_obj=http://www.giganticdownload.com/update.php&p_var=./paid/en-us/virus-alert-default&p_elm=7&p_lex=13277&p_lid=en-us&p_lng=en&p_lqa=3&p_lqe=1&p_lst=0&p_lsu=24&p_pro=2&p_vep=9&p_ves=0&p_vbd=2007&p_hid=d648e841-f16f-4657-8a0c-46ca8568f1b1)  you have mentioned in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/668790/how-do-you-find-the-file-that-avast-anti-virus-is-blocking-connections-from-no) follow-up question, i see that **URL:Mal** could be the culprit that is trying to harm your system.

If one of the software that you installed is trying to access a **malicious website** or **vicious URL** then the AV comes into action by detecting it as a kind of virus infection.

It is important to pay attention to this issue or else your **web browser** might get affected. Then there will be a lot of stuff will happen to your browser (like unknown add-ons, tool bars, unwanted ads,etc.,) and your AV will detect even the normal websites you visit as harmful once your browser is infected.

Now all you have to do is just to confirm whether the detected **Updater.exe** is harmful and carry on with the removal process(I found [Remove URL:Mal](http://blog.mightyuninstaller.com/remove-urlmal-how-to-get-rid-of-urlmal-completely/) and [Removal Mal](http://removevirusinfections.blogspot.in/2013/08/urlmal-removal-instructions-how-to-get.html) articles that gives a walk through on the removal of URL:Mal infectors). If you are not sure about the existance of such malwares in your system there are plenty of ways to sweep them off using a good **anti-malware** with an **updated anti-virus software**.

Comment: Why wouldn't the antivirus detect the actual file and only block its connection?

Comment: @Celeritas Ofcourse that is what your AV did. It blocked the connection that could harm your computer and informed you which one (Updater.exe in your case) is attempting it and even its path. What more do you expect ? And also the actions that AV takes is depends on your settings(Notify/quarantine/delete permanently). AV does not delete the files without your permission because some files can be very important to you and don't want them to be deleted and find some other way for solving it.

Comment: The message says "malicious URL blocked" which is not the same as "virus found". It doesn't give the option to delete. Also it is very different that a possibly legitimate file is trying to access an infected site than the file itself being a virus.

Comment: I am not telling you that the file is a virus. Only tou can find out the trustworthy of that file since it is you who installed it. what is malicious ? - intending or intended to do harm. Any thing that harms your computer is detected by the AV as an infector. You can name it "virus" or "infector" or whatever.